# how to do simple toggle panel for webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

how can I do the effect of toggle pannel for my webpart without coding? 
and if there is other effect that I can use.
I use SharePoint2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a hide show toggle effect ? I am afraid you will not have a no-code solution for toggle. You will have to atleast write some Jquery code. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/toggle/) are some good sample which you can test and select as per your needs.